# Overriding Bootstraps Table Row Colors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, odoo-8

I am new to Bootstrap and trying to override Bootstraps default table colours, particularly the rows, I would like to define another solid colour. I have tried overriding with a new class but Bootstrap keeps displaying default colours. I do not want to edit the original Bootstrap CSS file. Please note I am trying to do this using Odoo version 8, but I'm sure that would not matter.

Below is my table:

```
   <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="filters">
                    <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#" disabled=""></th>
                    <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" disabled=""></th>
                    <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" disabled=""></th>
                    <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" disabled=""></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Larry</td>
                    <td>the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

From what I can tell looking at the Bootstrap CSS I can see this is the code that is being applied:

```
}
.table > thead > tr > th,
.table > tbody > tr > th,
.table > tfoot > tr > th,
.table > thead > tr > td,
.table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you've tried adding your own class and overriding (which is the correct way) without success, but please take a look below - I've got it working fine by adding my own `.custom` class to  and then overriding with CSS using `.table.custom > thead > tr > td {}`

```css
.table.custom > thead > tr > th,
.table.custom > tbody > tr > th,
.table.custom > tfoot > tr > th,
.table.custom > thead > tr > td,
.table.custom > tbody > tr > td,
.table.custom > tfoot > tr > td {
  background-color: red;
  border-top: 4px solid #fff;
}
//for custom table row

.table.custom tr {
      background-color: red;
      border-top: 4px solid #fff;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table custom">
            <thead>
                <tr class="filters">
                    <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#" disabled=""></th>
                    <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" disabled=""></th>
                    <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" disabled=""></th>
                    <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" disabled=""></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>Larry</td>
                    <td>the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

NOTE: you'll have to do some work of course to get it looking the way you want it but it demonstrates the point.